# Sqlite Database Doesn't "Reset"

Tags: database, sqlite

I have an Rspec file that runs the following method before and after each "describe" test block:

```
  def self.reset
    commands = [
      "del #{CATS_DB_FILE}", #the "del" was changed from "rm" for windows
      "cat #{CATS_SQL_FILE} > sqlite3 #{CATS_DB_FILE}" # | was used before (pipe in linux)
    ]

    commands.each { |command| `#{command}` }
    DBConnection.open(CATS_DB_FILE)
  end
```

I'm running all of this in Windows command line. For some reason, the database overpopulates itself repeatedly; it seems that the database doesn't "clear" itself, so when another test block is run, the same attributes are added again. Does the syntax in the `commands` array above look okay? Kind of new to all this, would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: If you run these commands manually in a Windows command prompt, do you get the desired result?

Comment: Nope, I think the error is on the "del #{CATS_DB_FILE}" line. When I input that into the cmd line, the file is deleted, so for some reason, it seems that the file is not deleted each time when that method is executed...